# Tools to help retain knowledge from coursework?

Tags: united-states, coursework, learning

As second year undergraduate student, I've realized that I sometimes have a hard time recalling the core concepts from coursework in previous semesters. I imagine this would only gets worse as any student progresses through their academic career, so I want to take action early.

I'm wondering what tools exist to help students keep studying a course topic *after the semester is over*. This way students would constantly be applying knowledge they're interested in retaining, but without diving deep into a subject. For example, this could be something like a software solution that regularly quizzes me on course topics I've already covered.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: "I imagine this would only gets worse as any student progresses through their academic career." I found the opposite to be true. Once I got to grad school I *focused* more hence forgot less. Also, by the time you get to grad school you start developing a web of knowledge where most new things that you learn are connected to thinks you already know securely by multiple connections. Over the years since then I have forgotten much of what I've learned, but even now I have much clearer memories of the content of my grad school classes than I do of my undergraduate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your own university provides you with such software, it would probably be too hard for the software to know what topics you have studied exactly, and in how much detail. But you are right: if you do not work with your knowledge on a daily basis you will forget things. But this is not a problem. The "magic" solution you are looking for is called a job :).

Inevitably you will forget some of the things you do not work with every day. But your education will provide you with enough knowledge to look up the answers you need, and quickly be up to speed again.

The way I see one of the main goals of an MSc is to be able to read the scientific books and papers in your own field, and the fields close to it. This is how you will refresh and update your knowledge constantly when you start working in science.